# Show/Hide feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a feature using either jQuery or vanilla JS. My feature should be able to show/hide content on click. The initial task is easy enough and I'm able to show my hidden div using jQuery toggle, but I would also like to be able to switch my FA icon as well as the link text from 'Show content' to 'Hide content'.

[image]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHSmZ.png]

Comment: What have you tried? What's your problem? Did you do your research already? I'm sure numerous resources already exist which do exactly that.

Comment: I'm new to JS & jQuery. Have checked stack overflow and youtube and can't seem to find anything that fits my requirements. As I said, by using toggleClass and toggle I'm able to display the content on click, as well as change the icon (just like in the screenshots). Just when add in a function to change the text using the text method the icon disappears.

Comment: Just noticed the additional info comment (you can edit the question to add more details/clarification so they don't get "lost" in comments).  If you're using `.text()` to set the text, then add a `span` for the text and change that `$(this).find("span").text("...")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
.toggleClass(`.fa-check .fa-cross')
```

add one as the default.

Toggle text can be handled by either not using `.toggle` (using .show/.hide) instead or by including a `span` for each text and toggling those.  Or by having 2 buttons and toggling those.

Example snippet (needs fa icons)

```js
$(".toggle").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("collapsed expanded")
    $(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down")
});
```

```css
.wrapper { border: 1px solid #CCC; width: 200px; }
.wrapper .details { border-top: 1px solid #CCC; }
.wrapper .toggle.collapsed > div.details { display:none; }
.wrapper .toggle.expanded > .more { display:none; }
.wrapper .toggle.collapsed > .less { display:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='toggle collapsed'><i class='fa fa-chevron-up'></i>
    <div class='more'>more</div><div class='less'>less</div>
    <div class='details'>details</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can apply the same logic for the text to the icon as well if preferred (include 2 `<i class='fa...`) and then use css to show/hide them based on the class on the parent.

You can also add some css transition so it's less jumpy, or you can use `$(this).find(".more,.less").slideToggle()` instead of just toggle to add an effect.

Comment: Thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

There are dozens of ways to do it. Below is a step-by-step tutorial.

This should work, assuming you have already included jQuery.

```
<img id="imgtog" onclick="toggle()" src="someimg1.png">
<div id="content" hidden="">content</div>

<script>
var tog = false;

function toggle()
{
   if(tog == false)
   {
      $('#content').removeAttr('hidden');
      $('#imgtog').attr('src', 'otherimage2.png');
     tog = true;
    }
    else
    {
       $('#content').attr('hidden', '');
       $('#imgtog').attr('src', 'someimg1.png');
      tog = false;
    }
}

</script>
```